# value is not updating into dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to compare values from two dict1 and dict2 and i need to update new value in dict1.

Below are the code

```
dict2 = {'partname1': {'jarversion': '1.0', 'jarname': 'jar1.jar'},
         'partname2': {'jarversion': '2.0', 'jarname': 'jar2.jar'},
         'partname3': {'jarversion': '3.0', 'jarname': 'jar3.jar'}}

dict1 = {1: {'partition_name': 'avs',
             'jar': [{'jarversion': '1.0', 'jarname': 'jar1.jar'}, {'jarversion': '5.0', 'jarname': 'jar5.jar'}]},
         2: {'partition_name': 'ivs',
             'jar': [{'jarversion': '4.0', 'jarname': 'jar4.jar'}, {'jarversion': '2.0', 'jarname': 'jar2.jar'}], }}
```

code i am using below.

```
res = []
for _, v in dict2.items():
    res.append(v['jarname'] + v['jarversion'])

def cmp_value(rstring='', lstring=''):
    print('rstring', rstring)
    print('lstring', lstring)
    if rstring == lstring:
        print("true.......................................")
        return True
    else:
        return False


for key, val in dict1.items():
    print(val)
    for eachval in res:
        for i in val['jar']:
            if cmp_value(eachval, "%s%s" % (i['jarname'], i['jarversion'])):
                i['overwrite'] = 'true'

            else:
                i['overwrite'] = 'false'


print(dict1)
```

The results is

```
{1: {'partition_name': 'avs', 'jar': [{'jarversion': '1.0', 'jarname': 'jar1.jar', 'overwrite': 'false'}, {'jarversion': '5.0', 'jarname': 'jar5.jar', 'overwrite': 'false'}]}, 2: {'partition_name': 'ivs', 'jar': [{'jarversion': '4.0', 'jarname': 'jar4.jar', 'overwrite': 'false'}, {'jarversion': '2.0', 'jarname': 'jar2.jar', 'overwrite': 'false'}]}}
```

As you see above all the "overwrite" value showing "false".
I am using pretty old python version 2.2.1 So ( sets and comprehension) wont work here. So with the above i can add any code

Comment: res code updated

Comment: You are overwriting the value of "overwrite". Check your loop. Perhaps you meant to use `if all(cmp_value(..) for eachval in res)`

Answer (score 1):

This is an algorithmic bug.
Your final value of the `overwrite` is set based on the **last** comparison.
It means that you would want to stop iterating over `res` once `cmp_value(...)` returns true.

You can try to swap the loops hierarchy and break the loop on **true**:

```
...
for i in val['jar']:
    for eachval in res:
        if cmp_value(eachval, "%s%s" % (i['jarname'], i['jarversion'])):
            i['overwrite'] = 'true'
            break
        else:
            i['overwrite'] = 'false'
```